# Using exit(), I get "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, traceback, try-except

I am learning Python and while trying to build an authenticator (login), I came upon this error.

```
credentials = {
    "Peter" : "123",
    "Chris" : "Ga1",
    "Michael" : "uwu",
    "Steve" : "xdx10"
}
entered_username = None
entered_password = None
username_errors = 0
password_errors = 0

while True:
    entered_username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    entered_password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    try:
        if entered_password != credentials[entered_username]:
            password_errors += 1
            if password_errors == 5:
                print("Your account has been locked for security reasons.")
                exit()
            print("Wrong username or password, try again.")
            continue
        else:
            print("success 1")
    except:
        username_errors += 1
        if password_errors + username_errors == 5:
            print("Please try again at a later time.")
        print("Wrong username or password, try again.")
        continue
    print("Welcome {}! Your password is {}.".format(entered_username, entered_password))
    break
```

so the `exit()` in question is about halfway through the code, in the `if` block of an `if` block of the `try` block.

Running the code and failing five times to enter the right password is supposed to make it print "Your account has been locked for security reasons." and then exit the code. However, it makes this traceback.

If I take away the `exit()`, the traceback disappears.

I don't know if it's maybe because of the `try`/`except`, but I've been trying to fix this problem for like a freaking hour and I'm dying inside (ಠ_ಠ).

EDIT : didn't paste traceback (facepalm)

```
Your account has been locked for security reasons.
Wrong username or password, try again.
Please enter your username: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/stem1401python/py200603/login_form_v3/stem1401_python_login_form_v3.py", line 42, in <module>
    entered_username = input("Please enter your username: ")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I'll additionally add this: I don't know why it's still printing out stuff after exit(). Like right after `print("Your account has been locked for security reasons.")` there's `exit()`

Comment: Where is your file IO code? Your exception seems like it has something to do with files

Comment: Try to rellace the exit with sys.exit() (import sys as well....)

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: ``sys.exit()`` works by throwing an exception. Your ``except:`` block discards all exceptions. Never use a bare ``except:``, always catch only specific exception that you expect.

Comment: Also try using `os._exit()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Your account has been locked for security reasons.
Wrong username or password, try again.
Please enter your username: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/stem1401python/py200603/login_form_v3/stem1401_python_login_form_v3.py", line 42, in <module>
    entered_username = input("Please enter your username: ")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The above error is due to the `pycharm ide` when it reaches the `exit()` line in the file it just `closes the file not terminates the running process` so when it reaches the continue it goes back to the loop and when it try to get input() it `throws a traceback that the IO ops can't be done in closed files`, so that's the problem if you run the file using idle it will run successfully without the traceback because `it will automatically kill the running process when file is exited` , or if you want to run the code in pycharm just use `os.abort()` instead of `exit()` since it will abort the process

```
credentials = {
    "Peter" : "123",
    "Chris" : "Ga1",
    "Michael" : "uwu",
    "Steve" : "xdx10"
}
entered_username = None
entered_password = None
username_errors = 0
password_errors = 0
import os
while True:
    entered_username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    entered_password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    try:
        if entered_password != credentials[entered_username]:
            password_errors += 1
            if password_errors == 5:
                print("Your account has been locked for security reasons.")
                os.abort()
            print("Wrong username or password, try again.")
            continue
        else:
            print("success 1")
    except:
        username_errors += 1
        if password_errors + username_errors == 5:
            print("Please try again at a later time.")
        print("Wrong username or password, try again.")
        continue
    print("Welcome {}! Your password is {}.".format(entered_username, entered_password))
    break
```